# perl chmod help required to set file permission

Tags: perl

Below is my code:

```
foreach my $node (@switch_list) { 
    chomp $node;
    print "$node \n";
    my $f3 = ">$node.txt";
    chmod 0755, $f3;
    open FILE3, "$f3" or die "Could not open file:$! \n";
}
```

Here I want to create many files with full permission but it seems that file created with 
permission: 0640 and not 0755.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing:

```
my $f3 = ">$node.txt";
chmod 0755, $f3;
```

So Perl looks for a file named `>$node.txt`.

Instead do:

```
my $f3 = "$node.txt";
chmod 0755, $f3;
open FILE3, ">", "$f3" or die "Could not open file:$! \n";
```

Comment: @Pradeep: What do you mean?  `open` recognizes the single argument `">foo.txt"` as a request to create (`>`) a file named `"foo.txt"` (though the 3-argument form is better); `chmod` doesn't treat `">"` as special, so it tries to act on a file called `">foo.txt"`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Pradeep was responding to my comment, which I removed because it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

codaddict are correct in that you have included the mode in your `$f3` string, which probably makes `chmod` fail.

However, a better solution than to use `chmod` might be to use [`umask`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html), which I believe works with `open` (although the documentation only specifically mentions `sysopen`, and I am not in linux so I can try it out).